# copy() and file_get_contents() both return image with 0 bytes, only on one server, with allow_url_fopen = On

Tags: php

On a shared hosting server `copy()` returns `true` but the image (.jpg) is 0 bytes.  Same for `file_get_contents()`. I also used curl, but the image is 0 bytes.  I have tried this on three different servers (not shared hosting) and the images are retrieved with no problem.  The shared hosting server is running PHP 5.3.26, and allow_url_fopen is set to "On" - both the local and master value.

I'm at a loss for what I should try next (I've submitted a support ticket, but it's not my account so I have to wait for a 3rd party to forward the messages to me).  It looks like PHP can be configured with `--disable-url-fopen-wrapper` which may or may not override allow_url_fopen but this particular instance is not configured with that option (I just searched `phpinfo()`).

Are there any other settings I should be looking out for?

EDIT:
When I use `cURL` from the shared hosting server, I get:

```
* About to connect() to sub.domain.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ip.ip.ip.ip...
* Connection timed out
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
```

When I use it from any of the other servers:

```
* About to connect() to sub.domain.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ip.ip.ip.ip... * connected
> GET /Media/5555/3890066/635236788134810610.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: sub.domain.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 09 Feb 2014 17:18:18 GMT
< Server: MIIxpc/4.7
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< Last-Modified: Thu, 26 Dec 2013 23:20:43 GMT
< ETag: "125D3CBBB:52BCB9CB"
< Via: 1.1 iad.xpc-mii.net (MIIxpc/4.7 UNVERIFIED_CACHE_HIT Sun, 09 Feb 2014 17:18:18 GMT)
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Disposition: filename=635236788134810610.jpg
< Age: 23546
< Via: 1.1 ttn105008 (MII-APC/2.4)
< x-mii-cache-hit: 1, auth=1
< Content-Length: 63504
< Expires: Sun, 16 Feb 2014 23:50:44 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=628346
< X-Pb-Mii: Powered by Mirror Image Internet
< Via: 1.1 ttn107102 (MII-APC/2.4)
< 
* Connection #0 to host sub.domain.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

This is done with the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
//$fp = fopen('test.jpg','w');
$f = fopen('test_curlresponse.txt', 'w');
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_URL            => $url, 
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
      CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
      CURLOPT_STDERR         => $f,
    ));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

`curl_errono()` is returning 7 - `Failed to connect() to host or proxy`.  I can't help but think this is an issue with the host, because if I run this at *the same time* as I run it on another server, I get the image no problem.

Per php.ini, safe mode is turned off.  Again, I have a support ticket open, I just hate sitting and waiting for someone to get back to me :)

Thanks!

Comment: What are the response headers when you use `curl`? Might be the issue is some form of access denied instead of an issue on the server.

Comment: check phpinfo output, maybe some kind of safe mode is enabled

Comment: I added the response from 2 servers (one is the shared) @Wrikken; Safe mode is not enabled as far as I can tell @Lashane.

Comment: No connection to the ip: either a network problem (unroutable addess), or an overactive firewall? Or SELinux permission problems, but those a rares.

Comment: Finally got a response from the host: `I have made few changes in your account. Please check and let us know if the issue continues.` That's it, and it works now.  For the sake of answering this question, I will ask for more information.